# Sum values of cookies using Cookies.js plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cookies

I'm using [cookies.js](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) plugin to keep values in website after refresh or close tab. I upload files and get words number via AJAX, I put this value in an input text, a div and a cookie.

HTML:

```
<div id="result_words"></div>
<input id="numwords" type="text">
<div id="nw"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
//I obtain words number (response) via AJAX after upload file
$.post("myfile.php",{
  values:values
}).success(function(response){
document.getElementById('result_words').innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' name='wordcount' value='"+response+"'>";

var arr = document.getElementsByName('wordcount');
var tot=0;
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
    tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
    document.getElementById('nw').innerHTML = tot;
}

document.getElementById('numwords').value = tot;
document.getElementById('nw').innerHTML = tot;

Cookies.set("words", tot);
});
```

When load page put Cookie value on input and div:

```
var nwords = Cookies.get("words");

if(nwords>=0){
 $("#nw").html(nwords);
 $("#numwords").val(nwords);
}
```

This works great, but when I refresh and upload another file replaces previous value for new one and I want to sum this with previous value. For example, if I obtain 50, then refresh and upload another value with 20 words, I want to obtain 70 as new value in Cookie, input and div and still calculating when upload files.

I would like some help.

Comment: This you can do it when setting the cookie itself, get the previous value and add to the new value.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could find a solution putting div result_words content where store all word numbers of each file as a cookie value:

```
Cookies.set("words", tot);
var rwords = document.getElementById('result_words').innerHTML;
Cookies.set("wordcnt",rwords);
```

And when I load page add this:

```
var nwords = Cookies.get("words");
var wcnt = Cookies.get("wordcnt");

if(nwords>=0){
 $("#nw").html(nwords);
 $("#numwords").val(nwords);
}

if(wcnt!=''){
   $("#result_words").html(wcnt);
}
```